# Optimization Algorithm for Combining Nodes on a Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[Graph before and after clustering nodes $R_1$ and $R_2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGOJ9.png)

In the picture linked above, I have a graph with nodes $R_1$ through $R_5$ and vertices linking them. All the vertices are weighted 10 in this case, and a node can have any number of vertices attached to it; the vertices can have any positive integer weight. I want to essentially condense this graph down to one node by combining all the nodes. The computational cost of combining two nodes in the context of the program I'm running (these nodes actually represent operations on arrays, but it is not necessary to understand that to look at the problem I'm positing here) is the weights of all the edges "included" when combining any number of nodes. For example, in the picture, the cost of combining nodes $R_1$ and $R_2$ is $10*10 = 10^2$ since there is one edge between them and node $R_2$ also has a second, separate edge. The cost of combining all the nodes in the graph at once would be $10*10*10*10*10 = 10^5$, since there are five edges, all weighted 10, in the entire graph. However, by combining two nodes at a time in a strategic order, it is possible to reduce the cost to the order of $10^3$.

I want to write an algorithm that will help me combine nodes in an efficient manner; I've tried writing a simple greedy algorithm as well as a recursive algorithm that finds every possible combination and returns the cheapest. Both algorithms work as intended, but the recursive algorithm is prohibitively slow and the greedy algorithm doesn't do particularly well when compared to the minimum cost that the recursive algorithm finds. I have also tried reducing the run-time of the recursive algorithm through dynamic programming, but it appears that taking advantage of overlapping subproblems isn't really possible here; due to the great variety of weights that the edges can have, while overlapping subproblems occur occasionally, they are too rare to be worth taking advantage of.

I am not terribly well-versed in graph theory or combinatorics and have mostly been attacking this problem from a computer science standpoint (though I did make an attempt to search through graph theory questions here and on the Internet before posting), so I am posting here in the hope that this might be a known problem or similar to a known problem that I can take advantage of, or that anyone might have other advice for working on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the worked example for this operation : "However, by combining two nodes at a time in a strategic order, it is possible to reduce the cost to the order of $10^3$"